# Best way to adjust/observe algorithm parameters with Qt GUI

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, user-interface

I do have a couple of algorithm classes that do different computations. All these classes have different parameter sets. What I would like to achieve is to create a Qt GUI which acts as an observer for the algorithm parameters and let's the use make changes (some kind of MVC for the parameters). The widgets needed can be manually created (using Qt Designer e.g.) for each algorithm class. Another requirement is to keep the alorithms Qt free, they do have their own Signal/Slot mechanism though.

Currently the algorithms fire a signal whenever a value changes, this is translated to a Qt signal by a third party and then the UI updates accordingly. Whenever a UI widget changes a slot sets the appropriate parameters in the algorithm (while doing range checking, conversions, etc.). Currently all widgets belonging to a certain algorithm class call one unified slot, that checks all widgets belonging to this class (to reduce the number of Slots needed).

Very basic example:

GUI class

```
connect( m_notifier, SIGNAL( algo1ChangedParameters() ), this, SLOT( updateWidgets ) );

connect( m_my_spinbox_1, SIGNAL( valueChanged(int) ), this, SLOT( handleAlgo1ParameterChange() ) );
connect( m_my_spinbox_2, SIGNAL( valueChanged(int) ), this, SLOT( handleAlgo1ParameterChange() ) );

void handleAlgo1ParameterChange()
{
    Algo1Parameters p = m_algo1.GetParameters();

    p.param1 = /*spinbox 1 value*/;
    p.param2 = /*spinbox 1 value*/;

    m_algo1.SetParameters( p );
}

void updateWidgets()
{
    Algo1Parameters p = m_algo1.GetParameters();
    /* set spinboxes to values in p */
}
```

In this case m_notifier would translate between algorithm and Qt Signals.

My question:

- is there a better/standard way to implement this kind of algorithm GUI (e.g. doing range checks and conversion using some kind of Qt Widget value mapping or similar)
- are there standard ways of implementing GUI creation via visitor patterns if the GUI is automatically to be created?

Thanks!

Comment: Some simple explicit code please

Comment: added a basic example

Answer (score 0):

You can use Qt Model View Framework for this task. You can create new model class and implement its virtual methods and signalling (including `data()` and `setData()` methods and `dataChanged` signal). You can use `QDataWidgetMapper` to attach spinboxes to your model. Spinboxes will automatically reflect model data changes. And changes made by user will be automatically redirected to model's `setData` function. In the model implementation you can implement all necessary data processing logic (including range checks).

However this approach can easily lead to overcomplication, so use it carefully.